# What are the Tools for writing stories for Jbehave?

Tags: testing, bdd, jbehave

I was wondering whether there're any tools  assisting users in Writing stories for Jbehave ?

Comment: depends on what exactly you are expecting of a 'assisting' Tool?

Comment: something like template, auto-complete, eyepleasing, generating the mapped java class maybe

Comment: have you already tried the eclipse-solution i posted in my answer?

Answer (score 4):

Please don't "write stories for JBehave".

Have conversations with your business, and capture the scenarios they talk about, in something that is as close to their language as you can. Then write those down and use JBehave to map the natural language to steps.

This is what JBehave's aliases are for; so that you can capture conversations rather than forcing them into a form that you already have.

If you try to make those conversations match an existing framework, you're just programming using a different kind of language, and all of the problems that BDD is designed to help you with will still be there. You'll just be translating from your "JBehave steps" to the business language instead of from code. Worse, because it's English, people will *think* you understand what you're doing, instead of recognizing that you might have got it wrong. If you're using JBehave this way, you might as well use [a DSL](https://code.google.com/p/wipflash/source/browse/Example.PetShop.Scenarios/PetRegistrationAndPurchase.cs), which at least doesn't provide that illusion.

If you find that there's ambiguity in what the business are saying and you want to constrain the language that they use, talk about that rather than just doing it in JBehave. You may want to read the sections on "ubiquitous language" and "core domain" in Eric Evans' book, ["Domain Driven Design"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00794TAUG), as that will help to make the conversations you have more effective.

Conversation, not automation, is the heart of BDD.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best integration of jBehave is in Eclispe. There you have a complete Story Editor for this (and of course syntax highlighting and so on). Maybe this is what you want.
Have a look at this page: http://jbehave.org/eclipse-integration.html

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Jira plugin called "JBehave for Jira" designed specifically to help write JBehave stories (or capturing scenarios as Liz put it more correctly) without a need for an IDE, hence perfect for non technical people.

See the following link for more info -  https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.jbehaveforjira.plugin